# Android Studio Fragment method never launch

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting problem, that my Fragment method never launches..

No errors or anything else.

MainActivity - OnCreate method ("GameLoop")

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LoadFile();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Collections();
                            SaveFile();
                            Refresh();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```

This is how I add fragments - Navigation

```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    String TAG = "";
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_clicker) {
        fragment = new ClickerFragment();
        TAG = "Clicker_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_upgrades) {
        fragment = new UpgradeFragment();
        TAG = "Upgrade_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_warehouse) {
        fragment = new WarehouseFragment();
        TAG = "Warehouse_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_postservice) {
        fragment = new PostserviceFragment();
        TAG = "Postservice_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_shop) {
        fragment = new ShopFragment();
        TAG = "Shop_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_market) {
        fragment = new MarketFragment();
        TAG = "Market_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_workshop) {
        fragment = new WorkshopFragment();
        TAG = "Workshop_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_garage) {
        fragment = new GarageFragment();
        TAG = "Garage_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_museum) {
        fragment = new MuseumFragment();
        TAG = "Museum_TAG";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_collections) {
        fragment = new CollectionsFragment();
        TAG = "Collections_TAG";
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, TAG).
                commit();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

MainActivity - Refresh(Method)

```
   public void Refresh(){

    ClickerFragment Clicker  = (ClickerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Clicker_TAG");

    UpgradeFragment Upgrade = (UpgradeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Upgrade_TAG");

    WarehouseFragment Warehouse = (WarehouseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Warehouse_TAG");

    PostserviceFragment Postservice = (PostserviceFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Postservice_TAG");

    ShopFragment Shop = (ShopFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Shop_TAG");

    if(Clicker != null) {
        Clicker.RefreshClicker();
    }

    if(Upgrade != null) {
        Upgrade.RefreshUpgrade();
    }

    if(Warehouse != null) {
        Warehouse.RefreshWarehouse();
    }

    if(Postservice != null) {
        Postservice.RefreshPostservice();
    }

    if(Shop != null) {
        Shop.RefreshShop();
    }
}
```

And Example of Fragment method

```
package com.crelix.crelix;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class ClickerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ClickerFragment newInstance() {
        ClickerFragment fragment = new ClickerFragment();
        return fragment;
    }



private TextView MoneyText;
private TextView MoneyPerTapTView;
private TextView BoxesText;
private TextView BoxesPerTapTView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

MainHolder Main = new MainHolder();

public void RefreshClicker(){
    MoneyText.setText("Money: " +Main.Money[0]);
    MoneyPerTapTView.setText("$ " + Main.Money[1] + " per tap");
    BoxesText.setText("Boxes: " + Main.Boxes[0] + "/100");
    BoxesPerTapTView.setText("Points " + Main.Boxes[1] + " per tap");
    progressBar.setProgress(Main.Boxes[0]);
}

public ClickerFragment() {
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clicker, container, false);
        MoneyText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MoneyText);
        MoneyPerTapTView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MoneyPerTapTView);
        BoxesText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BoxesText);
        BoxesPerTapTView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BoxesPerTapTView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        return rootView;

    }

public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RefreshClicker();


}
```

}

Comment: Do you need to do `executePendingTransactions()` after the commit?

Comment: @AlLelopath I don't really understand, what that is. But i think, that NO. I only need to refresh design. For example "Money" etc.

Comment: Could it be that they are loading but your layouts (either the container or the fragment layout itself) are causing the fragment to have a 0 height/width or are pushed off of the view? Do some fragments show and not others? Can you confirm that the fragment lifecycles are running?

Comment: @JonAdams All layouts are looking good. All are shown. These methods were working and refreshing when i made them on "Onclick" (click insade frame). They just dont work now..